# How do I return an exit code from a VBScript console application

Tags: vbscript

I Have an old vbs script file being kicked off by an AutoSys job. Can I, and how do I, return an int return value to indicate success or failure?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the answer :0)

```
 DIM returnValue
 returnValue = 99
 WScript.Quit(returnValue)
```

This seems to work well.

Comment: This is basically the same as what at @Rob posted, but may be better if you follow a convention of having a single exit point to the script (as the very last line), and then set  `returnValue` else where in the flow of your code.  Note that if you use that approach, you'll probably want to include on `On Error Resume Next` at the start of your script, to avoid implicit fatal errors.

Answer (score 65):

Try:

```
WScript.Quit n
```

Where n is the ERRORLEVEL you want to return

Comment: using `Quit` is undesired in cases where your script is activate withing another script. it will also stop the "main" script execution