# How do I let cmd know VB script has finished?

Tags: vbscript

I am using the solution from here to convert .csv to .xlsx:

[Convert .CSV to .XLSX using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606394/convert-csv-to-xlsx-using-command-line)

```
Dim file, WB

With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Resume Next
For Each file In WScript.Arguments
    Set WB = .Workbooks.Open(file)
    WB.SaveAs Replace(WB.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
    WB.Close False
Next    
.Quit
End With

WScript.Echo "Done!"
```

I have tried running this from .cmd and everything works, but when you run it from cmd, the command just finishes right away though the vb script still processes. Is there a way to let cmd know that vb has finished? I'm trying to create a batch file, so it would be great to know when this part is finished before moving on to the next step. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not quite a duplicate, but the following seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/187040/4996248

Comment: Maybe something like [`start "" /wait wscript yourscript.vbs`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) could suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running the script by itself:

```
C:\path\to\your.vbs
```

Doing so runs the script with the associated interpreter, which in a normal installation is [`wscript.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875526.aspx). Basically, the above is the same as

```
wscript.exe C:\path\to\your.vbs
```

`wscript.exe` launches scripts asynchronously, meaning it returns immediately while the script continues running in the background. For running scripts synchronously you need to use the commandline interpreter [`cscript.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff920171.aspx) instead. Add the parameter `//NoLogo` to suppress the copyright/version info message.

```
cscript.exe //NoLogo C:\path\to\your.vbs
```

With that execution of your batch script will continue only after the VBScript terminates. Using the [`call`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732835.aspx) command is not required.

You can change the default interpreter from `wscript.exe` to `cscript.exe` by running `wscript.exe //h:cscript` or `cscript.exe //h:cscript` as an administrator.

Comment: What's the `//` all about? Command switches are `/`. From the `cmd` prompt `cscript.exe /nologo` works fine.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `cscript /?`. I suppose the original intention was to distinguish between parameters for the interpreter and parameters for the script. Both `//NoLogo` and `/NoLogo` seem to work nowadays, but using the double slashes for interpreter parameters became a habit of mine.

Comment: Ok, never noticed as host parameters have always worked for me with `/`. Always learning.

Comment: Thank you very much. cscript works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

By using **call** [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) the batch script will wait until the script engine process terminates. **/T** allows you to set a timeout. The process gets interrupted if the run time exceeds the limit specified in seconds.

```
@echo off
call cscript //T:10 "%~dp0example.vbs" 
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

Use [wscript.quit](http://ss64.com/vb/quit.html) in your vbs script to return an exit code. Error Numbers are stored in the **Err.number** property.

```
On Error Resume Next
WScript.Sleep 2000
Err.Raise 507 ' An exception occurred
wscript.quit Err.number
```